# cert.pfx file is not recognized for upload by azure ssl after download from azure ubuntu server

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ssl, visual-studio-code, pfx

I am trying to upload am SSl certificate .pfx file from my new azure ubuntu server to azure. The security certificate was created on the server using Let's encrypt and seems to have converted to a .pfx file correctly(?) however is not visible locally or in the azure file upload.

[image: downloading the file via vscode]

[image: The file seems to download but is not visible in the local file directory and cannot be viewed when selected.]

[image: The file is not displayed in azure and when I select the option recommended it does not recognise the file name]

I am not sure if the problem originates from a) converting the file to pfx on server b) downloading the file from server via vscode c) something on my local machine or d) the file uploader on the azure site?

Help is sincerely appreciated, many thanks in advance

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919074/you-receive-an-error-message-when-you-try-to-import-an-ssl-private-key

Comment: Could you try this [solution](https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.tech251497.html)?